# Using a reference to a bash string variable in sed

Tags: shell-script, sed, quoting

I'm a relative Linux novice.  Suppose that I have a text file `a.txt` that contains the following text:

```
A
B
C
```

Now, if I want to change the text on line 2 (which contains `B`), I can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed -i '2s/^.*$/X/' a.txt
```

to change the `B` to `X`, for example.

But now suppose that I want to write an `sed` command that changes the text on line 2 to something that *includes* a bash string variable.  I want to change the text on line 2 to `fname="myaddress"`, where the quotation marks are included explicitly, and where `myaddress` is a ***bash string variable*** (defined somewhere else).  To try to do this, I have created a bash shell script called `mytest.sh` and containing the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

myaddress="/home/"
echo fname=\"$myaddress\"

head a.txt
sed -i '2s/^.*$/fname=\"$myaddress\"/' a.txt
head a.txt
```

Now, `echo fname=\"$myaddress\"` prints `fname="/home/"`, which is the text that I *want* to be on line 2 of `a.txt`.  However, `sed` instead prints `fname="$myaddress"` to line 2 of `a.txt`, probably because it is inside the surrounding apostrophes.  In other words, the output of the above bash shell script is:

```
fname="/home/"
A
B
C

A
fname="$myaddress"
C
```

My question is, how can I get `sed` to actually print the *value* stored in `myaddress` and referenced by `$myaddress`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems: First, as already noted by Kevin, shell variables need to be enclosed in double quotes if they are to be expanded by the shell. Second, your replacement string contains a `/`, so you cannot use `/` at the same time as a delimiter for `sed`. If you know that some character, say `,`, will definitely not occur in the replacement string, you could use that character as `sed` delimiter, so you get

```
sed -i '2s,^.*$,fname="'"$myaddress"'",' a.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want the replace to work whatever the content of the variable is, you have to escape characters in the variable that are special on the right hand side of a `s` command in `sed` which are:

- the delimiter itself (above, you used `/`)
- `&` which is replaced by the matched string
- newline which needs to be escaped
- `\` which is used to escape all of the above and introduce `\1`, `\2`...

Like:

```
escaped_var=$(printf '%s\n' "$var" | sed 's:[/&\]:\\&:g;s/$/\\/')
escaped_var=${escaped_var%?}

sed "s/regexp/$escaped_var/g"
```

As that's quite cumbersome, you might want to use `perl` instead:

```
v=$var perl -pe 's/regexp/$ENV{v}/g'
```

The equivalent of `sed`'s `2s` would be:

```
v=$var perl -pe 's/regexp/$ENV{v}/g if $. == 2'
```

Though in your case of course, you'd rather write it:

```
v=$myaddress perl -pe '$_ = "fname=\"$ENV{v}\"\n" if $. == 2'
```

The other advantage is that it works with binary data as well and you can use a `-i` option for in-place editing while with `sed`, you could only do that on systems where `sed` is the GNU `sed`.

Also note that the NUL character cannot be stored in an environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

The shell doesn't interpret variables within single quotes. You need to change them to double quotes. Since your variable has slashes in it, you should use a different delimiter:

```
sed -i "2s|^.*\$|fname=\"$myaddress\"|" a.txt
```

Note that I escaped the end-of-line `$` so it isn't interpreted by the shell. In this case it wouldn't be, but you should get in the habit of escaping `$`s you want to keep in double quotes. You could also do this using a couple pairs of quotes:

```
sed -i '2s|^.*$|fname="'"$myaddress"'"|' a.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.  When I type either of the above suggestions, though, I get this error message: `sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to \`s'`.  I'm trying to figure out if I typed something wrong, or if something else is wrong.

Comment: It's because your variable has slashes in it, see my edit.