# Delete a matching line in a file doesn't work

Tags: shell-script, sed, scripting

So, I have this piece of a code:

```
while read line 
        do
            if [ $line = $maddr ] ;
            then
                sed -i '/${maddr}/d' mailinglist
                found=true
                break

            fi
        done < mailinglist
```

If the read line matches my variable (a string) then delete the whole line.

When it didn't work, I tested it with the flag **-x**, the pattern is found and it enters the if cycle, it even does the sed command, but the line stays there.

(I create the "mailinglist" file in the script, so I thought, maybe it didn't have write permission, but I checked it and as far as I can tell, I do have the permission - I basically don't change anything about permissions in the script).

I believe the sed command there is right (I have to edit the file and save it right away). 
Can you help me?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87380/using-a-reference-to-a-bash-string-variable-in-sed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works just fine like this only not with single-quotes but double. I tend to overcomplicate things.

```
while read line 
        do
            if [ $line = $maddr ] ;
            then
                sed -i "/$maddr/d" mailinglist
                found=true
                break

            fi
        done < mailinglist
```